# How to do role based authorization in Azure with Asp.net webapi backend and front end as Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, authorization, azure-active-directory, role

How I can do Azure role based authentication in webapi backend. I see tons of example for Asp.net MVC but none for webapi with front end as Angular. I have hosted my website developed in angular with backend as webapi and hosted it on Azure and enabled the Authentication/authorization as Azure Active directory in Azure website. Also I have done the setup for AD application for roles in its manifest files. After I hit website, I have to authenticate and then after authentication it redirects to my website . During my website load it calls my webapi and the Authentication token  with claims is passed to my webapi. In webapi I am checking for InRole or [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] and based on that I am allowing access. However in token roles do not flow by default . So I query graph api to get roles by extracting the information from token and pass it to graph api to get roles. I am doing query in Owin Startup class to fetch role, But I am not able to get success. Is there anything wrong with the code,  Please help . The code is copied below. Also I could have used ADAL JS library in Angular to authenticate with AD but I don't need to do so as I have enabled authentication in Azure website using the option "Authentication/Authorization". The layer of Authentication in website will do all token validation and forward it to webapi.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using Owin;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OneMap.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // Apply bearer token authentication middleware to Owin IAppBuilder interface.
        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var tenantId = Common.Configuration.GetConfigurationSetting("ida:Tenant");
            // ADAL authentication context for our Azure AD tenant.
            var authenticationContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(
              $"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}", true, TokenCache.DefaultShared);

            // Secret key that can be generated in the Azure portal to enable authentication of a
            // specific application (in this case our Web API) against an Azure AD tenant.
            var applicationKey = Common.Configuration.GetConfigurationSetting("ida:Password");



            // Root URL for Azure AD Graph API.
            var azureGraphApiUrl = "https://graph.windows.net";
            var graphApiServiceRootUrl = new Uri(new Uri(azureGraphApiUrl), tenantId);
            var clientId = Common.Configuration.GetConfigurationSetting("ida:ClientId");
            // Add bearer token authentication middleware.
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
              new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
              {
                  // The id of the client application that must be registered in Azure AD.
                  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = clientId },
                  // Our Azure AD tenant (e.g.: contoso.onmicrosoft.com).
                  Tenant = tenantId,
                  Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                  {
                      // This is where the magic happens. In this handler we can perform additional
                      // validations against the authenticated principal or modify the principal.
                      OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                              // Retrieve user JWT token from request.
                              var authorizationHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                                        var userJwtToken = authorizationHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();

                              // Get current user identity from authentication ticket.
                              var authenticationTicket = context.Ticket;
                                        var identity = authenticationTicket.Identity;

                              // Credential representing the current user. We need this to request a token
                              // that allows our application access to the Azure Graph API.
                              var userUpnClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn);
                                        var userName = userUpnClaim == null
                                ? identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value
                                : userUpnClaim.Value;
                                        var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(
                                userJwtToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

                              // Credential representing our client application in Azure AD.
                              var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, applicationKey);

                              // Get a token on behalf of the current user that lets Azure AD Graph API access
                              // our Azure AD tenant.
                              var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                                azureGraphApiUrl, clientCredential, userAssertion).ConfigureAwait(false);

                              // Create Graph API client and give it the acquired token.
                              var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                                graphApiServiceRootUrl, () => Task.FromResult(authenticationResult.AccessToken));

                              // Get current user groups.
                              var pagedUserGroups =
                                await activeDirectoryClient.Me.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                                        do
                                        {
                                  // Collect groups and add them as role claims to our current principal.
                                  var directoryObjects = pagedUserGroups.CurrentPage.ToList();
                                            foreach (var directoryObject in directoryObjects)
                                            {
                                                var group = directoryObject as Group;
                                                if (group != null)
                                                {
                                          // Add ObjectId of group to current identity as role claim.
                                          identity.AddClaim(new Claim(identity.RoleClaimType, group.ObjectId));
                                                }
                                            }
                                            pagedUserGroups = await pagedUserGroups.GetNextPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                                        } while (pagedUserGroups != null);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        throw;
                                    }
                                }
                  }
              });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `roles` claim only issued in the id_token. After you change the manifest of app(refer [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims)), you can using the SPA get the id_token and access the web API according the roles via the id_token.

And there is no need to using the  Authentication/authorization since you have protect the web API using the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` OWIN middleware. To authenticate the SPA you can refer this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp).

Comment: Thanks Fei for help. I was trying to use Authentication/authorization instead of using Angular ADAL library, I thought why should I write extra code if everything is provided here,  but in this role claim is not coming. As you said it will only come in id_token and I am going to implement ADAL for angular. So there are two types of token (Access token and id_token). I hope I will get ID_Token using angular adal library  ?

Comment: When we protecting the web app by enable Authentication/authorization feature,  we can call the web API using cookies and token issued by **easy auth**. It is not possible to call the web API using the id_token issued by Azure AD. And in this scenario, it doesn't support the roles claim. The right solution is that protecting the web API using the OWIN component, and get the id_token contains the roles info using angular adal library and call the web API using this token.